# Modifier key bug with Adobe Design Standard CS4 (Mac OS 10.6.6)

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

When I launch the Adobe apps, they ask me if I want to delete the preferences file. I say 'no'. Then, when using the apps, none of the tools seem to work properly, eg in Illustrator, I can't move objects without it duplicating the object. Photoshop constantly displays the contextual menu icon that usually only appears when you hold down the control key.

I can't do any work in them when this happens, so I am forced to log out and then back in. They work for a while and then this annoying bug happens again.

I think it must be to do with the modifier keys (command option and control). I think Adobe's apps must think I'm permanently pressing the modifier keys down - the thing is, no other app on my machine has this problem!

Does anyone else experience this? Or have a fix for it? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Running: Mac OS X 10.6.6 on an iMac. Adobe CS4 Design standard installed.

Comment: ive been on the phone with adobe customer support for about a week now, one or two hours a day. so far the guy has not been able to figured it out. I tried installing CS 4 in a brand new mac.. so no previous versions and have not been able to get it install. So out of frustration I asked if I could get another copy, but since they already released CS 5 they have no more CS4's; and they wont send me an upgrade, even after wasting huge amount of time on the phone with them they promise that they will call the next day to resolve the issue and either they dont call or just cant solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by some other application on your system like 1password, Things, Tweetie, moveAddict, etc. which allows you to press keyboard combinations to invoke some custom behavior.

There was a bug or change in behavior in the Mac OS X 10.6.5 update in the deprecated `CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, ...)` API.

There is a post in the Adobe forums about this, where one of the Adobe engineers posted a link to a utility which attempts to fix the behavior:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3296632#3296632

(Of course, Adobe's official stance is to stick with 10.6.4: [Alert "Delete the Adobe Photoshop Settings file?" | Tools, functions behave strangely | Photoshop CS5 | Mac OS 10.6.5, 10.6.6](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/881/cpsid_88159.html))

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, and explains why the behaviour has only happened recently (since I updated to Mac OS X 10.6.5). I'll try the utility.